# UIScrollView frame is changed by changing Simulator device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode9

I have simple ViewController which displays images using UIScrollView which has constraints attaching it to the (top, leading, trailing) of the superView, and a UIPageControl, it works fine on iPhoneX simulator

[image]

When I run it on iPad Pro 9.7" simulator, the output is

[image]

After changing the **View as** attribute in the storyboard from iPhoneX to iPadPro 9.7" it worked well

[image] [image]

This is the logic I use to calculate **scrollviewContentSize** & **slidesSize**

```
 override internal func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tutorialScrollView.delegate = self
    viewModel = TutorialViewModel()
    configurePages()
    setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
    configurePageControl()
}

private func configurePages() {
    if let viewModel = viewModel {
        createSlides(tutotialPages: viewModel.getTutorialPages())
    }
}

private func createSlides(tutotialPages: [TutorialPage]) {
    for page in tutotialPages {
        if let slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(BUNDLE_ID, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as?  TutorialSlideView {
            slide.configure(title: page.title, detail: page.details, image: page.image)
            slides.append(slide)
        }
    }
}

private func setupSlideScrollView(slides: [TutorialSlideView]) {
    tutorialScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * (CGFloat(slides.count)), height: tutorialScrollView.frame.height)
    tutorialScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
        slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: tutorialScrollView.frame.height)
        tutorialScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
    }
}
```

Can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to print view's frame in setupSlideScrollView method to ensure it is correct? There is no guarantee that it will be correct in the viewDidLoad method if you use AutoLayout. Sometimes it will be, sometimes not. I assume in this particular case, it happened to be correct on iPhone X, but incorrect on iPad.

If that's the problem, you should set contentSize and slides' frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Adding slides as subviews should stay in viewDidLoad/setupSlideScrollView because viewDidLayoutSubviews usually gets called multiple times.

Comment: calculating slides frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews() did the job, thanks!